# Can Symfony Bundle be used in non-Symfony project (f.e. Zend)?

Tags: symfony

Can I reuse my Bundle created in Symfony in non-Symfony project, f.e. Zend? (Or I only can reuse Components?)

What about services from that Bundle?

Comment: Bundle (in the usual case) is something as symfony "app". 
Usually you can't run symfony app without symfony on zend, it is not very logical ..
Components from other side are stand alone symfony "libraries" so they can be used anywhere..

Comment: ok, thanks. Bonus question: is it common/ is it make sense to create Component from simple Bundle with simple functionality (with some services) to reuse in another non-Symfony project?

Comment: If you need to reuse some service inside a Symfony and non-symfony  projects , you can just make some kind of separate library and to include and extend it at all of your projects symfony and none symfony projects.
Composer allows you to  include directly git project so you have just to configure it on all the project which are using this library.

Answer (score 3):

A Symfony bundle can certainly be included in with other projects, via a `composer.json` & `composer.lock` file - it doesn't mean that there is any useful code to run within that bundle however.

If there is useful code as part of the bundle, then you can use it directly, but a Symfony Bundle is just a library that will usually include some Symfony-specific configuration.

Best practice for a bundle is to put any useful, common code, into a separate library (which could be used independently - such as what Symfony calls a 'Component'), and then enable that code (for example creating Symfony services, or configuration) with the bundle configuration.

There have been projects that are Symfony bundles, and also have the configurations for other frameworks as well, such as Silex, and also appropriate Laravel configurations within the same codebase.